# Grep differences between OSX and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, grep, vcf-variant-call-format

I have written a script that takes three user inputs:

1. The name of a text file with rows corresponding to a chromosome and basepair position, for example `extract.txt`.
2. The name of a VCF file to search through for the values in the text file and extract, i.e. `test.vcf`.
3. The desired output name of a new VCF file that contains the extracted rows from `test.vcf`

For those unfamiliar with VCF files, there is a lot of complex header info but the only header line that matters in this problem context is the final header line that begins with `#CHROM`. A toy example of one of these files looks like this (Note: in a VCF file these columns are tab separated but I am not sure how to format that here):

```
#CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT
Chr06 5567134 . T C 999 PASS DP=13782;VDB=0.0302;AF1=0.7154;AC1=1312;DP4=1987,2142,4337,4552;MQ=39;FQ=999;PV4=0.49,1.5e-10,0,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567140 . G A 999 PASS DP=13537;VDB=0.0304;AF1=0.7489;AC1=1374;DP4=1744,1858,4383,4621;MQ=39;FQ=999;PV4=0.8,0.068,0,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567195 . G T 999 PASS DP=12016;VDB=0.0284;AF1=0.384;AC1=704;DP4=3311,4518,1537,1850;MQ=37;FQ=999;PV4=0.0026,0,0,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567224 . TAAAAA TAGAAACAAAAA 999 PASS INDEL;DP=13190;VDB=0.0352;AF1=0.1229;G3=0.7854,0.1806,0.03405;HWE=1.71e-05;AC1=225;DP4=4930,5006,542,685;MQ=40;FQ=999;PV4=0.00035,1,0,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567247 . T A 999 PASS DP=14383;VDB=0.03;AF1=0.1233;G3=0.7772,0.1986,0.02415;HWE=0.022;AC1=226;DP4=6484,6134,587,654;MQ=41;FQ=999;PV4=0.0062,9.3e-07,0,0.16 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567444 . TAAAAAA TAAAAAAA 999 PASS INDEL;DP=10303;VDB=0.0235;AF1=0.6037;G3=0.1784,0.4375,0.3841;HWE=0.0162;AC1=1107;DP4=1996,2224,2158,2446;MQ=46;FQ=999;PV4=0.7,1,6.3e-30,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567497 . AG A 999 PASS INDEL;DP=5243;VDB=0.028;AF1=0.07142;G3=0.873,0.08398,0.04299;HWE=0.000541;AC1=131;DP4=2297,2010,0,146;MQ=46;FQ=999;PV4=0,0,0.00097,0 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567499 . TAAA TGGCCAAATAAGCCACTCAAAAGAAATACAGCCAAAAACATCTACAAA 999 PASS INDEL;DP=5243;VDB=0.0273;AF1=0.3508;G3=0.4662,0.2686,0.2652;HWE=1.95e-12;AC1=643;DP4=1993,1638,195,545;MQ=46;FQ=999;PV4=0,1,5.1e-18,0 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567583 . G C 999 PASS DP=12372;VDB=0.0279;AF1=0.09276;AC1=170;DP4=4794,5928,512,569;MQ=42;FQ=999;PV4=0.095,1,5.5e-31,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
Chr06 5567628 . G T 999 PASS DP=12657;VDB=0.0244;AF1=0.1049;AC1=192;DP4=5230,6194,197,578;MQ=40;FQ=999;PV4=1.2e-29,9.8e-06,0,1 GT:PL:DP:SP:GQ
```

A toy example of the txt file of items to extract looks like this:

```
Chr06\t5567140
Chr06\t5567583
Chr06\t5567224
```

I have created this txt file to explicitly contain the VCF (tab) delimiter between the Chromosome and position values.

I have a bash script that works when I test it on my local OSX computer.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reset getopts
OPTIND=1

usage="$(basename "$0") [-h] [-i] [-v] [-o] -- program to extract loci from VCF files

where:
    -h  show this help text
    -i  input text file containing loci to extract
      CHR and BP columns must be separated by appropriate delimiter
    -v  VCF file to extract loci from
    -o  output file name
"


# Read in variables
while getopts ":hi:v:o:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    h) echo "$usage"
   exit
   ;;
    i)
      input=$OPTARG
      ;;
    v)
      vcf=$OPTARG
      ;;
    o)
      output=$OPTARG
      ;;
    esac
done

echo
echo "File containing SNP positions: '$input'"
echo "VCF file to extract from:      '$vcf'"
echo "Output filename:               '$output'"


LC_ALL=C grep '#CHROM' $vcf > $output

while IFS= read -r line
do

LC_ALL=C grep "$line" $vcf >> $output

done < $input
```

When I upload this file to my Linux server to run at scale it breaks down. The grep command in the while loop, i.e. `LC_ALL=C grep "$line" $vcf >> $output`, is unable to match anything in the larger VCF file.

Troubleshooting, I have figured out that the script works on the server if I change the text file so that the entries are no longer `Chr06\t5567140` and are now just `5567140`. Which just proves that the entries are contained within the file I am searching but something is failing in expanding the CHR-tab-BP pattern to match.

Obviously, I could just change all my text files and be done with the problem but this will make my tool less generalizable and I am now just curious why this script worked locally but fails on the server.

Any help is greatly appreciated, or commentary on how to improve my existing code. Let me know if anything about the question is unclear.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I got the script working. I simply had to change my text file formatting to use the actual tab character instead of the literal `\t`. The fact that using `\t` worked on OSX but not on Linux suggests that OSX grep is capable of interpreting this character while GNU grep is not (as @Sundeep pointed out in the comments below). Putting this edit here in case anyone has a similar issue in the future.

Comment: when you mention `Chr06\t5567140` is it `\t` or an actual tab character? `printf '1 a\tb 2' | grep 'a\tb'` will fail but `printf '1 a\tb 2' | grep $'a\tb'` will work because grep doesn't understand `\t` (at least GNU grep doesn't)... also, instead of using shell loop, you can use `grep -f`.. and `awk` is better suited for column based processing

Comment: I had the same Q, thanks Sundeep! But an excellent first Q (if a little over the top). (and I agree that `awk` seems much better suited for this). Now read about [mcve] and think above what is the minimal bit of code to demonstrate this problem. It seems like you have that already. And of course if you post just the minimal, then others will conmplain about lack o context so ;-> ... ++ from me. Good luck and keep posting.

Comment: @Sundeep it is a literal `\t` not the actual tab character. I changed my command to `LC_ALL=C grep $'$line' $vcf >> $output`. This executes `grep $'Chr06\t5567140' test.vcf >> output.vcf` which I believe is what you suggested but it still doesn't work.

Is it be easier to change my text file to contain the actual tab character instead of `\t`? I will try `grep -f` but want to get this working first. My goal is to find and extract the entire matching row, I didn't see how I could use `awk` but would love to see an example.

@shellter I will try to be more minimal moving forward, thanks.

Comment: `$'$line'` won't work out... you'll have to transform the input file first, use `sed 's/\\t/\t/'` on the file containing `Chr06\t5567140` and then pass the modified file to grep

Comment: or if you have `GNU grep` with `-P` option, you could use `grep -P` instead of changing `\t` to actual tabs